# Advice on 401k rollover to IRA

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, rollover

Basic question probably. I m looking for advice on rolling over a portion of amount in my 401k to an IRA.
My needs are: a) to eliminate tax on withdrawal from IRA
b) Have flexibility of withdrawal from IRA whenever I need
c) Minimum risk on investment.

I understand self-directed investing IRA may be suitable, but does it meet the above requirements? How much does it cost to rollover the amount from 401k to IRA?

Please advise with all options. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you still employed by the company associated with the 401(k)?  Does the 401(k) have a Roth option? do you already have a traditional or Roth IRA?

Comment: Yes still employed. 401k does have a Roth option. I don't have traditional or Roth IRA yet.

Comment: Step 1 is to ask your plan administrator if they allow “in-service rollovers”. If not, you cannot move 401K money to an IRA until you leave the company. Not all plans offer this (IMO it’s fairly rare).

Answer (score 4):

Rolling over from a 401(k) to an IRA does not have any "cost". If you are rolling pre-tax funds into a after-tax (Roth) account, you would pay tax (but no penalty) on the converted amount. It would be added to your "income" for that year and be taxed at your marginal tax rate.

But, addressing your needs:

> a) to eliminate tax on withdrawal

I assume this means that you'll be rolling to a Roth IRA. In that case, as stated above, you'd have to pay the tax on the converted amount at that time, or when you file, which might result in underpayment penalties. So it's really a wash from a tax standpoint since you could just as well invest the tax you'd pay into a Roth separately. It just *accelerates* the tax due, it does not *eliminate* or *reduce* it. The bet on that move is that your marginal tax rate now is less than it will be at retirement.

Since you mentioned that your company has a Roth option, this would also eliminate tax on withdrawal for those contributions (employer matches are always done pre-tax and are taxed at withdrawal).

> b) Have flexibility of withdrawal from IRA whenever I need

If your company allows in-service withdrawals (which a rollover would be) then why is that not an option?

> c) Minimum risk on investment.

Does your company not offer lower risk funds in its 401(k)? In my experience, companies offer funds that have varying levels of risk, which fixed income funds being lower risk, and even money market funds if want effectively zero risk (but no real growth either).

A self-directed IRA is really only necessary if you want to invest in things that aren't publicly traded, like physical real estate or private equity. However, the rules are ***much more restrictive***, since you can't invest in things in which you or your family has a direct benefit (e.g. you can't invest in a rental property and stay in it, keep some of the rent, or pay yourself for maintenance). So you would need to be very careful about what you buy within the IRA, and you can typically get similar investments through traditional means, like Real Estate ETFs.

Comment: Thanks it definitely helps to let me start thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The one Really Good reason I've heard to roll over 401k to IRA is that for a very specific case (both being Roth, I think, but don't take my word for it) that may reduce your Minimum Required Distribution, potentially letting you continue claiming the tax advantaged status of that money a bit longer. Of course that only applies when RMDs become an issue, which I think is around age 72; I feel no need to do anything special before then. (And if you think your budget will have you drawing out more than the RMD each year, you don't have to do anything about it after then either.)

Otherwise: My 401k, at least, has perfectly reasonable investment options and I don't feel any need to try to optimize beyond that. There is a *slight* data tracking hassle in having my personal investments and my 401k investments in separate-but-similar mutual funds, but again it isn't enough that I consider it worth doing anything different. It got me here; it can continue carrying me. If playing with money excites you, great; all I want is good returns for minimum effort.

Comment: There was a change to RMD rules for Roth 401(k): https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/retirement-plan-and-ira-required-minimum-distributions-faqs "Designated Roth accounts in a 401(k) or 403(b) plan are subject to the RMD rules for 2022 and 2023. However, for 2024 and later years, RMDs are no longer required from designated Roth accounts. You must still take RMDs from designated Roth accounts for 2023, including those with a required beginning date of April 1, 2024."